# Multilingual store emails

Tags: admin, template, email

I have a magento with 4 languages: spanish, english, french and italian. When a customer does an order, the order email is sent in his language. I mean, if a customer does an order in the English Store, the email send to the customer is in english. Up here all right.

The problem is I need that email that the administrator is sent with every order is always in Spanish.

Comment: Are you a magento developer? If yes, I can share some thoughts

Comment: Yes, I am a magento developer.

Comment: I have updated the answer, try with that

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following steps.

1. Create a diffrent email template for each store from admin.
   System->Transactional Emails
2. Set diffrent email template for specific store.

   a. Go to System->Configuration

   b. Select Proper Store from top left corner.

   c. Go To Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order ->  "New Order Confirmation Template" set proper language template from here.

Comment: Yes, I did it for the email order that the customer receives. But I need a spanish template for ADMINISTRATOR. Because, if the customer does the order in french, my business won't understand it. I need a copy for the administrator in spanish.

Comment: For administrator, you need to overide magento default functionality to send email in spanish everytime. 
You need to overide app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php file and look into this 
public function queueOrderUpdateEmail() that is arround line no 1384.

Comment: @abbrt Check my updated answer, that will help you to do this. Please note that I haven't tested the code